# How can I wait for 2 observables with different return types?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I need to wait on 2 observables to process a request, the types of which are different, e.g.

```
observable1 = Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<Type1> => ...)
```

and

```
observable2 = Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<Type2> => ...)
```

How can I avoid nested subscriptions such as

```
observable1.subscribe(result1 => {
    observable2.subscribe(result2 => {
        ...
        <do something with result1 and result2>
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried

```
observable1.concat(observable2).subscribe(result => ...)
```

but that appears to read from both observables in turn.

I'm thinking along the lines of

```
observable1<???>observable2.subscribe((result1, result2) => ...)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct: concat will read from the observables in turn. To "join" them (by ordinal position), you will want to use `zip`:

```
const a$ = Rx.Observable.just(1);
const b$ = Rx.Observable.just(2);

const combined$ = a$.zip(b$, (x, y) => ({ a: x, b: y }));

const subscription = combined$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Note that the fact that the two streams are of different types causes no inconvenience when using `zip`, as a function must be provided to produce a new value from the two "zipped" values.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!